# Quick alternative for subsetting by time

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I have a dataframe that contains several months of minutely data of a security.
Data example:

```
  TICKER PER     DATE  TIME   OPEN   HIGH    LOW  CLOSE VOL OPENINT
1   RIM4   1 20/03/13 10:55 140000 140000 140000 140000   2       0
2   RIM4   1 20/03/13 12:19 140000 140000 140000 140000  32       0
3   RIM4   1 20/03/13 14:30 140000 140000 140000 140000   1       0
              DT            dateTime       date
1 20/03/13 10:55 2013-03-20 10:55:00 2013-03-20
2 20/03/13 12:19 2013-03-20 12:19:00 2013-03-20
3 20/03/13 14:30 2013-03-20 14:30:00 2013-03-20
```

I wanted to calculate mean and std.dev for every day. So I developed this script:

```
#progress bar
pbb <- winProgressBar(title="Example progress bar", label="0% done", min=0, max=100, initial=0)

#subsetting
mean <- rep(NA,rim4$date[length(rim4$date)]-rim4$date[1])
std.dev <- rep(NA,rim4$date[length(rim4$date)]-rim4$date[1])
daily <- data.frame(mean,std.dev)
names(daily) <- c("mean","std.dev")
daily$date <- NA
daily$date <- rim4$date[1]
for (i in 2:length(daily$date)) {daily$date[i] <- daily$date[i-1]+86400}


for (i in 1:length(daily$date)) { 
  subRim4 <- rim4[format(rim4$date, "%Y-%m-%d") == daily$date[i],5]
  daily$mean[i] <- mean(subRim4, na.rm = TRUE)
  daily$std.dev[i] <- sd(subRim4, na.rm = TRUE)
  setWinProgressBar(pbb, i/(length(daily$date))*100)
}
close(pbb)
```

It works but too slow. It takes approximatelly 5 min for my machine to manage 1 year of data. It's a bit irritating. Does R have ways to do this faster? And by the way how do I update % value in progress bar? It always show "0%" in my case? 
Thank everybody in advance.

Comment: If you posted a dput(head(object)) output it would not be such a PITA to get that data in a form for testing and demonstration. `format.POSIXct` lets you construct a vector that can be used for `ave` or `tapply` for aggregate `mean`s and `sd`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` is pretty fast for this type of operation.  Try (not tested since your data isn't really reproducible for the problem):

```
library(data.table)
data.table(rim4)[, list(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN)), by=DATE]
```

Alternatively, you can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
rim4 %.% group_by(DATE) %.% summarise(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN))
```

Hopefully this will be fast enough you don't need a progress bar.  Also (out of curiosity after Joshua posted about xts), some benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  rim4.dt[, list(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN)), by=DATE],
  rim4 %.% group_by(DATE) %.% summarise(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN)),
  apply.daily(x, function(d) c(mean=mean(d), sd=sd(d))),
  times=5
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                         expr       min        lq    median
#             rim4.dt[, list(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN)), by = DATE]  45.15606  48.94687  53.58172
#  rim4 %.% group_by(DATE) %.% summarise(mean(OPEN), sd(OPEN))  50.42578  50.60166  50.78464
#    apply.daily(x, function(d) c(mean = mean(d), sd = sd(d))) 589.46499 592.49094 596.35476
```

I'm not sure if this is representative.  Here is the data:

```
library(xts)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(21)
size <- 1e6
val <- rnorm(size)
times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-03-28"), by="-1 min", length.out=size)
x <- xts(val, times)
rim4 <- data.frame(DATETIME=times, OPEN=val)
rim4$DATE <- format(rim4$DATETIME, "%Y-%m-%d")
rim4.dt <- data.table(rim4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an actual time-series class (like xts) and many things can be done a lot easier:

```
library(xts)
set.seed(21)
x <- xts(rnorm(1e6), seq(Sys.time(), by="-1 min", length.out=1e6))
y <- apply.daily(x, function(d) c(mean=mean(d), sd=sd(d)))
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution @JoshuaUlrich but when I subset my dataframe to create my X, I had an error when running y:    " Error in xts(x) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object".  I used POSIXct date format.

Comment: @BiXiC: then the `order.by` argument you passed to `xts()` is not `POSIXct`. It would be much easier to help if you provided a minimal, reproducible example.